# Memoize a NumPy vectorized function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function **is_prime(n)** which returns *True* if *n* is prime and *False* otherwise. In NumPy I am looping, checking if an array contains primes, and the start of the array will be identical through every iteration, so I want to memoize the **is_prime(n)** function to avoid a lot of unnecessary calculations.

Since I have an array, I want to vectorize **is_prime(n)** so I can apply it on arrays element by element, NumPy style. I do this with one line from the NumPy tutorial (shown later)

I also use a memoization template I found on the net:

```
def memoize(function):
    cache = {}
    def decorated_function(*args):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        else:
            val = function(*args)
            cache[args] = val
            return val
    return decorated_function
```

Then:

```
is_prime = memoize(is_prime)
```

**BUT**, is V_prime now correctly memoized if i **now** vectorize the memoized **is_prime** function?:

```
V_prime = np.vectorize(is_prime)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well lets test it.

```
import numpy as np

def test(input):
    return input

def memoize(function):
    cache = {}
    def decorated_function(*args):
        if args in cache:
            print 'cached'
            return cache[args]
        else:
            print 'not cached'
            val = function(*args)
            cache[args] = val
            return val
    return decorated_function

test = memoize(test)
print test(9)
print test(9)
test = np.vectorize(test)
print test(9)
print test(10)
print test(10)
```

I get this on my machine.

```
not cached
9
cached
9
cached
cached
9
not cached
10
cached
10
```

so yes, it is memoize, on my machine using numpy 1.6.1

Comment: Oh well, that was clever! Thank you!

Comment: no problem, memoization is quite cool, though be careful since it can consume quite a bit of memory depending on what types of objects you are working with... people tend to use dedicated objects instead of dictionaries to control/monitor memory and destroy/remove objects when memory is low or they haven't accessed them in a while.